# Formatting multiple SELECT statements with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

Currently have a script that unions around a dozen SELECT statements, and example of two of these along with an example of the results is shown below.

```
DECLARE @Age TABLE (name VARCHAR(30), total FLOAT, percentage FLOAT) 

INSERT INTO @Age
    SELECT '0-18', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPerson p
                INNER JOIN tblClient c ON c.intPersonID = p.intPersonID
                WHERE ISNULL(dbo.fncReportClient_Age(p.dteBirthdate, GETDATE()), '') >= 0 AND ISNULL(dbo.fncReportClient_Age(p.dteBirthdate, GETDATE()), '') <= 18), ''

UPDATE @Age
    SET percentage = ROUND((SELECT total FROM @Age WHERE name = '0-18')/(SELECT SUM(total) FROM @Age) * 100, 2)
    FROM @Age
    WHERE name = '0-18'
Etc.


SELECT 
    g.nvhGenderName, 
    COUNT(*),
        ROUND(COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100, 2)
FROM 
    tblClient c 
    LEFT JOIN tblPerson p ON p.intPersonID = c.intPersonID
    LEFT JOIN tblGender g ON g.intGenderID = p.intGenderID
GROUP BY g.nvhGenderName

UNION ALL 

SELECT * FROM @Age
```

Results example below:

```
Name    |   Total   |      %    |
---------------------------------
Male    |   6514    |   60.32   |
Female  |   4285    |   39.68   |
0-18    |   279     |   1.58    |
19-24   |   1748    |   9.93    |
25-34   |   5423    |   30.80   |
35-64   |   9546    |   54.21   |
65+     |   614     |   3.50    |
```

I would like to display these results horizontally as opposed to vertically, I think it is possible to do this with PIVOT but have never really used them. An example of how I want the data to be displayed is shown below:

```
Gender  |   Total   |   %   |   Age     |   Total   |   %   |   
-------------------------------------------------------------
Male    |   6514    | 60.32 |   0-18    |    279    | 1.58  |
Female  |   4285    | 39.68 |   19-24   |    1748   | 9.93  |
        |           |       |   25-34   |    5423   | 30.80 |
        |           |       |   35-64   |    9546   | 54.21 |
        |           |       |   65+     |    614    | 3.50  |
```

In particular I am not sure how I would use a pivot to combine the multiple (12) SELECT statements that require it.

Any help on how to format this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is just two pivot result sets, one over Gender and one over Age, that are just "glued" together. Are you sure this is the way you want to present the data? If so - maybe it's better to deliver two query results to the visualisation engine and combine them there?

Comment: SQL isn't designed for "presentation" (especially "pretty prsentation") How will you deliver this report to your users? in HTML? using PHP? (if so, then use PHP/HTML for this)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I believe the layout really *should be* achieved elsewhere, the following may work for you. Clearly I cannot test it so, without the benefit of testing here goes:

```
WITH myCTE AS (
      SELECT
            COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 0  AND oa.age < 19 THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) c0019
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 19 AND oa.age < 25 THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) c1925
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 25 AND oa.age < 35 THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) c2535
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 35 AND oa.age < 65 THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) c3565
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 65                 THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) c65on
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN g.nvhGenderName = 'Male'     THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) cmale
          , COUNT(CASE WHEN g.nvhGenderName = 'Female'   THEN p.intPersonID ELSE NULL END) cfemale
          , COUNT(*) ctotal
      FROM tblClient c
      LEFT JOIN tblPerson p ON p.intPersonID = c.intPersonID
      OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT
                  dbo.fncReportClient_Age(p.dteBirthdate) AS age
            ) AS oa
      LEFT JOIN tblGender g ON g.intGenderID = p.intGenderID
      )
SELECT
       ca.Gender, ca.Total2, ca.Pct, ca.Age, ca.Total2, ca.Pct2
FROM myCTE
CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES
           (1, 'Male' , t.cmale ,  (cmale * 100.0 / ctotal),  '0-18', c0019, (c0019 * 100.0 / ctotal))
         , (2, 'Female',t.cfemale,(cfemale * 100.0 / ctotal), '19-24', c1925, (c1925 * 100.0 / ctotal))
         , (3, NULL,NULL,NULL, '25-34', c2535, (c2535 * 100.0 / ctotal))
         , (4, NULL,NULL,NULL, '35-64', c3565, (c3565 * 100.0 / ctotal))
         , (5, NULL,NULL,NULL, '65+'  , c65on, (c65on * 100.0 / ctotal))
     ) AS ca (rn, Gender, Total2, Pct, Age, Total2, Pct2)
ORDER BY ca.rn
;
```

The second (lower) part of the query above uses a technique for `unpivoting` data that combines `cross apply` with `values` and this allows us to "layout" each row of the wanted final result row by row.

Using a `CTE` (the upper part of the query above) isn't essential, it could be moved into a subquery instead, but the query inside the `CTE` should be trialed standalone first and it should produce all the numbers you need in one pass of the data (assuming that the gender table doesn't disturb the count results). Note that using `count(case expression here)` removes the need for multiple separate queries. I suspect you don't need left joins by the way, and if that is true you could also change the outer apply to a cross apply. Note that the apply is used to execute your function, and by doing it ths way we are able to reference the result of that function by an alias in the remainder of the query (I used "age" as that alias).

I am unsure why you involve a client table when counting the persons table. I suspect it isn't needed. If my suspicions are correct the CTE detail could be replaced by this:

```
  SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 0  AND oa.age < 19 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) c0019
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 19 AND oa.age < 25 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) c1925
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 25 AND oa.age < 35 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) c2535
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 35 AND oa.age < 65 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) c3565
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN oa.age >= 65                 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) c65on
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN g.nvhGenderName = 'Male'     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) cmale
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN g.nvhGenderName = 'Feale'    THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) cfemale
      , COUNT(*) ctotal
  FROM tblPerson p
  CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
              dbo.fncReportClient_Age(p.dteBirthdate) AS age
        ) AS oa
  INNER JOIN tblGender g ON g.intGenderID = p.intGenderID
```

Comment: by the way, this suggestion is  "formatting a single pivot query using unpivot"  so quite different to your question title :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create VIEW view_name AS

SELECT * FROM (
  select ColumnName1,ColumnName2 from TableName
) as s
PIVOT (
Sum(ColumnName2)
  FOR ColumnName3 in ("Row1","Row2","Row3"
  )
) As pvt


DROP VIEW view_name;


Select * from view_name
```

Comment: It's not obvious that this answer is really addressing what the OP is asking.  It's nice clear code, but what does it do?  The question is over a year old, so assume that the OP has moved on and doesn't care anymore.  In that situation, unless the answer has changed (new technologies), or you can substantially improve on the existing answers (with detailed explanation), it's probably not worth answering.